# How can I initialize iterator fields on the first call to next()?

Tags: rust

I've come across a commond pattern where I have an `Iterator` whose fields I'd like to initialize in the first call to the `Iterator`'s `next()` method. The solution I've always come up with is to make that field an `Option`, and check `is_none()` on every call to `next()`, initializing the field if it is `None`.

For example, say I wanted to create an `Iterator` called `MultFirst` which took another iterator, and multiplied the first element to all the other elements. I don't want to just get the first element when my `MultFirst` struct is initialized, because getting the first element could be expensive and that should be done when we start iterating through the `MultFirst` struct. So, I use the `Option` solution:

```
struct MultFirst<A, I: Iterator<A>> {
    first_element: A,
    iterator: I,
}

impl<A: Mul<A,A>, I: Iterator<A>> Iterator<A> for MultFirst<A,I> {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<A> {

        if self.first_element.is_none() {
            self.first_element = self.iterator.next()
        }

        match self.iterator.next() {
            Some(x) => Some(self.first.unwrap() * x),
            None => None
        }
    }
}
```

This works just fine, but I would like to avoid checking `is_none` each call to `next` for performance. Is there some way I could accomplish this? I was thinking maybe after the first call to `next`, I could just call `map` and somehow let the `Map` struct take over for all subsequent calls to `next`. But I'm not sure if I can even do that. Is this possible, or is there another way I could accomplish this initialization without checking `is_none` every time?

Answer (score -1):

The `next` method is statically resolved and will always resolve to the same function, which must implement the code for both the case when the iterator is initialized and for when it is not. You could have your `struct` store a function pointer that the `next` method calls, which would allow you to change behavior by changing the function pointer, but that would add a level of indirection and might have more overhead than calling `is_none`.

Typically, you would handle the initialization during the creation of the iterator. If your initialization is expensive, instead of passing the iterator around, pass around a value that can be used to create the iterator on demand.

Comment: How specifically does one set the state? Like you use the mutable reference and just set it in the next if null?